# Working with CSOM for SPList, SPGroup manipulation from my laptop/desktop

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, csom, prerequisites

Wanted to know how can I access the list items, list manipulation,access group members(of a  SP 2013 ON-PREM farm's site collection) using from my desktop using CSOM?

I am new to CSOM, am using Win 8.1 lap and how can I do above operations againsta  site collection, thats hosted in a remote server.

What are the installables I need, on my lap to work on this CSOM?
am thinking of using CSOM with C# not with JSOM. What are the pre-requisites I have to have on my desktop / lap ?

I heard that, this is the reason, why MSFT has created CSOM for remotely accessing SP objects without login to the server.

**Note:** I have VS 2015 installed on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to install the SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK (available from [https://www.microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35585) to start with (I'm assuming SharePoint 2013 is the version you're working against? If not, look for the SharePoint 2010/2016 client components instead and install those.

This gives you the libraries that you'll need to reference from your code or scripts (I do quite a lot of work against Office 365 using CSOM PowerShell and you reference the online version of these libraries directly from the script).

You still need to authenticate against the server to perform actions.

There's a good basic introduction to performing CSOM operations at [https://dev.office.com](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)